# Does CoreOS have a cluster aware job scheduler?

Tags: cluster, coreos, scheduler, apache-mesos

Ive been checking out CoreOS and I'm impressed.   Before I found CoreOS I was looking at the [Mesos/Marathon/Chronos](http://mesosphere.io/learn/) stack as a "cluster kernel".

Given the following comparison:

```
init.d == Mesos+Marathon == CoreOS+Fleet
cron   == Mesos+Chronos  == CoreOS+?????
```

Im curious if CoreOS has a distributed Job Scheduler?   Or do most people just use Fleet to run something else?

Comment: What are you trying to build?  A large SMP (shared cpu and memory) a large distributed system for task workload or simply pairing services (apps) with appropriate resources?

Comment: At this point I'm more interested in the HA and Elastic properties of both projects.  Just info gatherng at this point.  I know that Mesos was built with a focus on resource sharing and can share the nodes with additional meta-frameworks like (Hadoop, Storm, etc).  Where as CoreOS seems to be more focused on supporting the operations team. BTW I noticed the CoreOS-fleet docs mentioned they are also working on resource-offers(interesting).  Anyway while comparing Mesos+Marathon+Chronos+Marathon-docker and CoreOS the biggest thing that seems to be missing was a HA JobScheduler like Chronos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fleet builds on top of Systemd and Systemd has a unit called a timer for cron like functionality.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/cron_functionality